# Convert Java Date/Calendat to HTML DatePicker

Tags: java, html, datepicker

I an trying to include a datepicker on my webdevelopment. The idea is that when the page loads the datepicker is set to the current date instead of showing in blank.
As the project is developed in Java and JSP, I am setting the current Date with
= new Date() or Calendar.getTime(), however when I send it to the datepicker it is read as a String.
I attempt to change it to instant and even format it with SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy") but nothing work yet.
Any ideas of how should it be faced?

```
  <%
        Date objDate;
        objDate = new Date(); //Alternative Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
  %>
  <html>
        <body>
              <input required type="date" name="datepicker" value="<%=objDate%>">
        </body>
  </html>
```

What I am getting now at page loading  is something like: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sM4PY.jpg)

And what I am looking for is: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pa3EF.jpg)

Comment: Your issue is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<%  

    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd");
    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();

%>
<body>
          <input required type="date" name="datepicker" value="<%=objDate%>">
</body>
```

You can change the date format as you want.

Comment: Thanks. It seems that the error resides that the datepicker only support yyyy.MM-dd format. Any other format is not recognized

Comment: If this answer solves your problem you can select the right mark next to my answer. This way people know that this question is solved.